# Using minted to define a new environment

Tags: environments, verbatim, minted

Can I define a newenvironment that has inside it a minted environment?

eg and environment that would be a quickhand for the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{9cm}
        \begin{minted}[frame=single]{ruby}
some minted code...
        \end{minted}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{a caption}
\end{figure}
```

I've tried using both the normal `\newenvironment` and the `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package. Nothing seems to work, as I always get:

```
Paragraph ended before \FV@BeginScanning was complete.\par  \end{terminal} 
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\begin{VerbatimOut} on input line 87 ended by \end{minipage}.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{environ}
\usemintedstyle{bw}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}

\pgfkeys{
    /terminal/.cd,
    caption/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{#1}}},
    label/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{\label{#1}}},
}

\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{}}

\NewEnviron{terminal}[1]{
\begingroup
    %\pgfkeys{/terminal/.cd,caption={}}
    \begin{figure}[\thefigpos]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{9cm}
\begin{minted}[frame=single]{ruby}
\BODY
\end{minted}

    \end{minipage}
    %\pgfkeysvalueof{terminal/caption}
    %\pgfkeysvalueof{terminal/label}
    \end{figure}
\endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{terminal}
a tryout
\end{terminal}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way since `minted` uses verbatim environments and isn’t designed to be included into other environments (mea culpa).

The following does what you want. It uses `minted` internals instead of the `minted` environment to achieve this. As a consequence, you need to put `\makeatletter` before the command if you want to include it into your `tex` file:

```
\newenvironment{terminal}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{frame=single}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{9cm}    
      \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
{%
      \end{VerbatimOut}
      \minted@pygmentize{ruby}
      \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}
```

Comment: If there's any possibility of including something like this snippet in the main documentation, or providing a more suitable mechanism for allowing users to embed minted environments in custom ones, that'd be much appreciated.