# Defining a command for a minted environment

Tags: macros, environments, minted

How can I define a newcommand macro or an environment for minted?
What is causing the problem that the following does not work?

```
\newcommand{\CppSourceCode}{
\begin{minted}[linenos=true, mathescape, xleftmargin=1cm]{c++}
 #1 
\end{minted}
}
```

output :

```
    ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.23 ...pe, xleftmargin=1cm]{c++} #1 \end{minted}}
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \CppSourceCode.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.23 ...pe, xleftmargin=1cm]{c++} #1 \end{minted}}
                                                  
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

(C:\Users\ZfMGPU\Desktop\Xetextest\main\main.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 35.
runsystem(pygmentize -S default -f latex > main.pyg)...executed.

 (C:\Users\ZfMGPU\Desktop\Xetextest\main\main.pyg)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.37 \CppSourceCode{asdasdasd asd asd }
                                       
You meant to type ## instead of #, right?
Or maybe a } was forgotten somewhere earlier, and things
are all screwed up? I'm going to assume that you meant ##.

! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input ` ##1 \end {minted}{asdasdasd asd asd }' between \begin{minted}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ...ncyVerb Error:^^J\space \space #1^^J}
                                                  
l.37 \CppSourceCode{asdasdasd asd asd }
                                       
This input will be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.
```

If read that post here [environment minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/using-minted-to-define-a-new-environment)
Iam using xelatex  in miktex 2.9
but is this the only solution?

Here one possibility:

Thats the minted command for having a new environment as in the package explained, probably should use this code !!

```
\newcommand\newminted[3][]{
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
       {\def\minted@envname{#2code}}
       {\def\minted@envname{#1}}
      \newenvironment{\minted@envname}
       {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{minted}[#3]{#2}}
       {\end{minted}}
      \newenvironment{\minted@envname *}[1]
       {\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{minted}[#3,##1]{#2}}
       {\end{minted}}}
```

Does anybody know why this works? whats the key difference? why does mine not work?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? It doesn't compile? What error are you getting?

Comment: edited, the above, there is something wron with preprocessing?

Comment: Verbatim environments like `minted` can't be enclosed in a macro. If the source code is already read as macro argument it can't be taken verbatim later.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See Martin's comment for the reason why your method doesn't work. See the `minted` manual, under "Defining shortcuts", for the `\newminted` command, which does what you want (but via an environment rather than a command):

```
\newminted[CppSourceCode]{c++}{linenos=true, mathescape, xleftmargin=1cm}
```

allows

```
\begin{CppSourceCode}
    c++ ; // goes here
\end{CppSourceCode}
```

If you prefer a command, use `\newmint` instead - see the manual for details.

Comment: But this doesn't allow for variables, right? Let's say I want to send some various labels before and after the minted code. How can I do it?