# How to define a custom command in minted environment

Tags: macros, minted, code

I am new to Latex so I might be missing something basic.
I need a custom command for code snippets. 
Normally I would write this:

```latex
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
firstnumber=182,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=white,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]{java}
int x = 3;
int y = x + 3;
\end{minted}
```

What I want to be able to use is this:

```latex
\code{182}{
int x = 3;
int y = x + 3;
}
```

This is my attempt at defining it:

```latex
\newcommand{\code}[2]{
\begin{minted}
[
frame=lines,
firstnumber=#1,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
bgcolor=white,
fontsize=\footnotesize,
linenos
]{java}
#2
\end{minted}
}
```

The `\begin{minted}` part and arguments are interpreted correctly, but my code (`#2`) is not printed, and the `{minted}` section ends when ended explicitly by a subsequent `\end{minted}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/defining-a-command-for-a-minted-environment

Comment: That helped, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from [Tiuri](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/103046/tiuri) really helped!

This is what I ended up doing in the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{environ}

\newenvironment{code}[1]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{minted}[
    frame=lines,
    firstnumber=#1,
    framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1.2,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    linenos]{java}}
 {\end{minted}}
```

and then:

```
\begin{code}{411}
int x = 3;
int y = x + 3;
\end{code}
```

This allows me to have blocks of code already formatted for which I only need to specify the starting line number and the code itself.

Output:

[image]