# New environment with minted

Tags: environments, minted

I want to create a new environment to transform this:

```
\begin{listing}
  \caption{some caption}
  \label{code:label}
  \begin{minted}[options]{language}
My code here
  \end{minted}
\end{listing}
```

into this:

```
\begin{mycode}{language}{some caption}{code:label}
My code here
\end{mycode}
```

I've tried the code from [Using minted to define a new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/using-minted-to-define-a-new-environment) without success.

**edit**

This is what I've tried:

```
\newenvironment{mycode}[3]{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{linenos,fontfamily=courier, fontsize=\scriptsize, xleftmargin=21pt}
  \begin{listing}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
    % \centering
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
{%
    \end{VerbatimOut}
    \minted@pygmentize{#1}
    \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
  \end{listing}}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}    
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mycode}[3]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{frame=single}% from fancyvrb
  \renewcommand{\minted@proglang}[1]{#1}
  \begin{figure}[htp]%% default placing
    \centering
    \caption{#2}\label{#3}
      \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
 {\end{VerbatimOut}
  \minted@pygmentize{\minted@proglang{}}
  \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
  \end{figure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}{latex}{some caption}{code:label}
My \code here
\end{mycode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm. I just replace the `figure` by `listing` and remove the `\centering`. Thanks @Hebert.
I didn't knew `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, but [now I do](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/11183). The `\minted@proglang` thing I can't get yet.

Comment: And I add an `\floatstyle{ruled}` at minted.sty. Exist an elegant way to do that?

Comment: look at the package `floatrow` how floating objects can be configured

Answer (score 5):

You don't need so complicated a code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{mycode}[4][]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{listing}
  \caption{#3}\label{#4}
  \begin{minted}[
    linenos,
    fontfamily=courier,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    xleftmargin=21pt,
    #1]{#2}}
 {\end{minted}\end{listing}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycode}{latex}{some caption}{code:label}
My \code here
\end{mycode}

\begin{mycode}[fontsize=\large]{latex}{some caption}{code:label2}
My \code here
\end{mycode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with a much easier definition of environments. It requires you to use but one more package, caption, in addition to listings and minted.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\newminted{python}{
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    numbersep=8pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=3mm
}
\newminted{latex}{
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    numbersep=8pt,
    xleftmargin=21pt,
    linenos,
    fontfamily=courier,
}


\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
\captionof{listing}{Example for python\label{python}}
\begin{pythoncode}
from xyz imort abc

print("Example python code")
\end{pythoncode}
\end{listing}

\begin{listing}
\captionof{listing}{Example for Latex\label{latex}}
\begin{latexcode}
\usepackage{latex}
\end{latexcode}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

There's an additional benefit to that. For example, with `\SetupFloatingEnvironment{listing}{name=Source Code}` you can change the display name of the environment. In the example it'd called Source Code 1, Source Code 2, etc.