# Simple minted \newenvironment

Tags: environments, minted

I'm trying to do a minted `\newenvironment`
I looked at this post [new-environment-with-minted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42393/new-environment-with-minted), but I would like to know if there's a more simple way to do that, like

```
\newenvironment{matlabcode}
        {\begin{minted}[mathescape,linenos=true]{matlab}}
        {\end{minted}}
```

In that case, I get a `FancyVerbGetLine` error
As I know, it seems that I should use \CustonVerbatimEnvironment

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the `\newminted` command as introduced in Section 6 of the »[minted](http://texdoc.net/pkg/minted)« manual.

```
\newminted{matlab}{mathescape,linenos=true}
```

You can use it in the same way as every other environment.

```
\begin{matlabcode}
% listing content
\end{matlabcode}
```

Note that the package will append `code` to the environment name by default as described in the manual.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I usually I get lost in the manuals with so much information. I'll take a look to that sections :)

Answer (score 4):

```
\newminted{matlabcode}{mathescape,linenos}

\begin{matlabcode}
...
\end{matlabcode}
```