# Usage of minted inside a new environment, inside IfFileExists

Tags: macros, environments, verbatim, minted

I want to conditionally load `minted` and define an environment, but after using `IfFileExists` I'm running into an error:

```
FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `resetoptions \setkeys {minted@opt}{frame=single} \begin {fi
gure}[htp] \centering \begin {minipage}{9cm} \begin {VerbatimOut}{\jobname .pyg
}' between \begin{Rcode}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.35 \begin{Rcode}
```

The solution for embedding the `minted` environment inside another came from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/using-minted-to-define-a-new-environment).

The code I'm running is shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\IfFileExists{minted.sty}{
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
    /terminal/.cd,
    caption/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{##1}}},
    label/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{\label{##1}}},
}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Rcode}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{frame=single}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{9cm}    
      \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
{%
      \end{VerbatimOut}
      \minted@pygmentize{r}
      \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}
\makeatother
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{Rcode}
# Als je specifieke elementen wil aanhalen gebruik dan
c(1,2,3,7,10,15)
# Voor een rij van elementen gebruik
1:15
\end{Rcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `\makeatletter` should be before `\IfFileExists` and `\makeatother` after `}{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\IfFileExists{minted.sty}{
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
    /terminal/.cd,
    caption/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{##1}}},
    label/.code={\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{\label{##1}}},
}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/label}{}
\pgfkeyssetvalue{terminal/caption}{\caption{}}
\newenvironment{Rcode}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \minted@resetoptions
  \setkeys{minted@opt}{frame=single}
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{9cm}    
      \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
{%
      \end{VerbatimOut}
      \minted@pygmentize{r}
      \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Rcode}
# Als je specifieke elementen wil aanhalen gebruik dan
c(1,2,3,7,10,15)
# Voor een rij van elementen gebruik
1:15
\end{Rcode}
\end{document}
```

You want to use macros with `@` in their name when you do the conditional definition, not when you use it.

Comment: A miracle... So why won't this work if I conditionally change the category code?

Comment: @1010011010 As I said, you must enable usage of `@`-command before using them. Since those commands are in the argument to `\IfFileExists`, you need to have `\makeatletter` *before* the argument is grabbed.