# Minted in new environment

Tags: environments, minted

I tried to create a new environment in which I wanted to use minted. Somehow it didn't really work and I found these two posts: [1.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42393/new-environment-with-minted) [2.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192944/minted-in-a-new-environment)

I then copied the code and tried to modify it for my needs. I want to be able to use `\begin{code}{label}`. This is what I have:

```
\newenvironment{code}[2]
{\VerbatimEnvironment
\minted@resetoptions
\setkeys{minted@opt}{frame=lines}% from fancyvrb
\renewcommand{\minted@proglang}[1]{#1}
\begin{figure}[htp]%% default placing
    \centering
    \label{#2}
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{\jobname.pyg}}
    {\end{VerbatimOut}
    \minted@pygmentize{\minted@proglang{}}
    \DeleteFile{\jobname.pyg}
\end{figure}}
\makeatother
```

I get several "FancyVerb" errors and undefined control sequences.

**EDIT**

Basically I want to define a new environment that produces the following:

```
\begin{minted}
    [
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    linenos,
    label=TestLabel
    ]
    {java}
    while(true){
    //Do stuff
    }
    \end{minted}
```

by just using `\begin{code}{TestLabel}...\end{code}`
[image]

Comment: You seem to be missing a `makeatletter` - check the source of your copy/paste.

Comment: It would help if you would add the errors you got to the question.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{code}[4][htp]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{figure}[#1]
  \centering
  \caption{#3}\label{#4}
  \begin{minted}[frame=lines]{#2}}
 {\end{minted}\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{code}{latex}{A caption}{label1}
Test of \LaTeX code
\end{code}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{code}[bp]{latex}{A caption}{label2}
Test of \LaTeX code
\end{code}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another version, where the argument refers to `label=`; I also changed `figure` into the more proper `listing` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{code}[2][htp]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{listing}[#1]
  \centering
  \begin{minted}[frame=lines,framesep=2mm,linenos,label=#2]{java}}
 {\end{minted}\end{listing}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{code}{Code 1}
while(true){
    //Do stuff
}
\end{code}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{code}[bp]{Code 2}
while(true){
    //Do stuff
}
\end{code}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg but there are some things I wanted to change:
I always want to use java ( I tried to change the `#2` into `java`)
And I also don't want to set a caption (only a label).
Also I noticed that the linespan is too small and the label is not showing. how would I change that?

Comment: @jobr97 Setting a label without a caption is useless.

Comment: but if I define a label in the options it shows up on top of the code block... I added an example to my post

Comment: @jobr97 I see nothing. Without a caption, the label will refer to whatever is the last number generated, so the result of `\ref` would be unpredictable.

Comment: now It should be visible

Comment: @jobr97 I added a new version, which should be what you want.